# types of encoding in xml

Tags: xml

How the encodings work? Which encodings can be used in XML?

```
To avoid errors
```

XML encoding while using PHP

I heard about

```
Character Encodings:
Source Encodings:
Target Encodings:
```

May i know what is the Difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use any ISO combination in your xml declaration but the ones you usually see is UTF-8 and iso-8859-1  (for europe). Usually UTF-8 is a good choice unless you have lot's of strange characters

EDIT: I think you're confusing something like an XSLT transformation/parsing with XML instead of just the actual XML document.

An XML document has a character encoding. That is declared through the xml declaration. When you parse/transform XML you can many times separately define what the source encoding is and what the encoding the output should have (the target encoding)

Comment: @mko:)These are the types of source encoding i know that ... actualy i want to know the character encoding and target encoding ?nd also some other encoding if available

Comment: 1. Conducted at the time of Parsing
2. Cannot be changed during parser lifetime
3. Types: UTF-8 (PHP uses this type for internal Document representation; Bytes up to 21)
4. US-ASCII (Single byte)
5. ISO-8859-1(Single byte; Default)

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Actualy i want to know the Basic difference between these encodings? how they works?

Comment: I don't think you ever really need to use anything different then UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoding. You only need to use UTF-16 for stuff like japanese, just make sure you save the file in the correct format as well as specify it in the declaration. Some parsers can use the Byte-order-mark to infer the encoding, but it's optional

Comment: @mko:) Question edited bro

Comment: UTF-8 works with "strange" characters (like UTF-16), most other encodings don't work with arbitrary "strange" characters. The only difference between UTF-8 and UTF-16 is the multiple of bits used. There are some characters that can be expressed in two bytes by UTF-16 and 3 by UTF-8.